# how do i get my 16bit pcm wav to load in google hangout app?

Tags: ffmpeg, google-api, wav, pcm

I have tried audacity, ffmpeg and several others. The ONLY file i can get my soundboard app to load is the goodday.wav that comes with the source code to their google media app, sample apllication.

has anyone been able to get their files to load and what program/settings have you used that worked?

Comment: I only know SoX do you mind?

Comment: @meda
I am using their AudioResource but it seems that loading from my self signed https server isn't possible. Perhaps if there was another https service with a trusted cert google would allow it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Audacity and converted my WAV to a 16 bit PCM WAV with 44.1KHZ sample rate.  That was the key for me.